# Can't find brightness controls in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, display, intel-graphics, brightness

I installed Linux Mint recently and then installed Nvidia drivers on my machine. There doesn't seem to be any brightness controls and the brightness keys arent working also. This happened after I installed Nvidia drivers. Before that I was able to change the brightness settings. I have Intel display driver as well, but don't know how to switch. Nvidia is in use.

Comment: Have you checked this https://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/ ?

Comment: @Rayleigh It covers only Intel drivers. I have both installed in my machine

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Here's what happened. I installed a new Linux mint on my laptop. But when I logged in, the screen was going black and non responsive(display drivers were not installed). I added `nomodeset` in the grub config which worked. Then I installed display drivers and forgot to remove the above setting from grub config. So there were no controls for the brightness. I removed the above setting and now everything works fine.

Comment: with nvidia proprietary driver installed add "nouveau.modeset=0" in grub config to let F6-F7 and the brightness slider working.